# Python function returning incorrect result

Tags: python, function

I'm new to programming in Python, so my apologies if this is a really basic question. For some reason, when I compile the following code and run the function pythagorean(2,3), I get the error:

```
Error: Both a and b need to be positive
```

I have the following code:

```
import math
def pythagorean(a, b):
    if a or b < 0:
        print("Error: Both a and b need to be positive")
    else:
        sum = math.pow(a, 2) + math.pow(b, 2)
        c = math.sqrt(sum)
        return c
```

From what I understand, the program should have skipped over that conditional and not printed the error to the screen since both a and b are greater than 0...right?

Answer (score 1):

You should change

```
if a or b < 0:
```

into

```
if a < 0 or b < 0:
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked!

Answer (score 0):

Try entering this:

```
bool(a)
```

If `a` is a negative number, or is 0, then it will be false. Otherwise, it will be true. Let's look at your code:

```
if a or b < 0:
```

is really...

```
if a:
if b < 0:
```

Since `a` will nearly always be true, just change the statement to...

```
if a < 0 and b < 0:
    # do something!
```